# How to play an mp3 once onClick in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio

i have a  that i want to play a very small mp3 once that is in my public folder in my react app, there are so many different solutions to playing audio but none that are simple for react, i tried react-360 but there was a problem with one of the modules.

i've tried some react audio libraries, but they seem to be for audio players, i dont need a play button and a pause and a volume and all that. just want a simple sound effect

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {

    var audio = new Audio("../public/sound.mp3")

    return (
      <Container>
            <img src={dwight} onClick={ audio.play() }/>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

(sound to play when click the image)

Answer (score 67):

**Hooks version (React 16.8+):**

Minimal version.

Place your music file (mp3) in the public folder.

```
import React from 'react';

function App() {
  let audio = new Audio("/christmas.mp3")

  const start = () => {
    audio.play()
  }

  return (
    < div >
      <button onClick={start}>Play</button>
    </div >
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You probably want to wrap the `audio` in `useMemo` or move it to outside of the component to prevent issues when the component re-renders

Comment: Am I missing something or is there no hook in this answer?

Comment: By “hooks version (React 16.8+)”, I think the OP meant React functional components version rather than class components. There is no hook here but there is a functional component.

Answer (score 15):

You can import the audio using import statement and create a Audio object and call the play() method using the instantiated object.

```
import React from "react";
import audio from './../assets/audios/success.mp3';

class AudioTest extends React.Component{

  playAudio = () => {
    new Audio(audio).play();
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.playAudio}>PLAY AUDIO</button>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AudioTest;
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Add to your render method`<audio id="audio"><source src="slow-spring-board.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></source></audio>`
2. And inside the script `document.getElementById('audio').play()`

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a function thats trigger play:

```
<Container>
    <img src={dwight} onClick={ () => audio.play() }/>
 </Container>
```

Comment: this seemed right but still did not execute the sound

Comment: @ChristopherDucote make sure you have right file path

Comment: it was auto generated by visual studio code i didnt type the path... hmmmm

Comment: @ChristopherDucote look at console, if there errors about file?

Comment: ```The error you provided does not contain a stack trace.
    at B (index.js:1588)
    at G (index.js:1905)
    at index.js:1920
    at index.js:1939
    at index.js:1420```

```Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'play' on 'HTMLMediaElement': Illegal invocation
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:147)
    at ```

Comment: @ChristopherDucote try ‘onClick={() => audio.play.call(audio)}’

Comment: i restarted the app, i believe its because my mp3 was outside the src folder, re formatting now AND i just noticed i never imported the mp3... WOOPS

Comment: ok we're back to where we started, same errors minus the illegal invocation one, this is at the end ```App.js:12 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The element has no supported sources.```

Comment: @ChristopherDucote ‘onClick={audio.play}’

Comment: OK finally, when i tried onClick={ () => audio.play() } , it plays the sound on page load, not on click

Comment: ‘onClick={audio.play}’  is an illegal invocation

Answer (score 0):

```
<Container>
    <img src={dwight} onClick={audio.play}/>
</Container>
```

By passing `audio.play` as the onClick handler, rather than `audio.play()`, you're passing the `play` function itself. `audio.play()` will instead *invoke* the function - if it also returned a function for some reason, then that function would be invoked on click.

Comment: Some explanation would be nice.

Comment: console reads Failed to execute 'play' on 'HTMLMediaElement': Illegal invocation

Comment: @Jimenemex ...?

Answer (score 0):

so i moved the sound and picture files INSIDE of the src folder, into assets, THEN changed the onClick function to a combo that finally worked, it looks like a double invocation did the trick

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <img src={dwight} alt="ds" onClick={() => audio.play()} />
        <h1> PRESS ME</h1>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Fragment } from 'react';
export default function PlaySound(props) {
    var savingCurrencySound = props.soundFile ?? 'https://example.com/audio/sound.mp3';
    var playCurrencySound = () => {     
        var audio = new Audio(savingCurrencySound);
        audio.play();
    }
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <img src={dwight} onClick={ () => playCurrencySound() }/>
        </Fragment>
    );
}
```

Comment: This solution was provided before, can you add more details to your answer so that if can differentiate of the others? Otherwise it looks like a copied answer.

Comment: @Cristik - the minor difference is to pass the relative url of sound file instead of file path of audio file.

Comment: Thanks, can you expand this on the answer? This will also increase its quality, as currently it's a code-only answer, a code that seems copy+pasted from another answer.

Comment: Already in response

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47686478/10818414) answer

here's the following worked code :

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const useAudio = url => {
  const [audio] = useState(new Audio(url));
  const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);

  const toggle = () => setPlaying(!playing);

  useEffect(() => {
      playing ? audio.play() : audio.pause();
    },
    [playing]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    audio.addEventListener('ended', () => setPlaying(false));
    return () => {
      audio.removeEventListener('ended', () => setPlaying(false));
    };
  }, []);

  return [playing, toggle];
};

const Player = ({ url = 'https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3' }) => {
  const [playing, toggle] = useAudio(url);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={toggle}>{playing ? "Pause" : "Play"}</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Player;
```

or you can use this playground [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ojmjxu)

Comment: The type of `toggle` in `Player` component is oddly `boolean | (() => void)` in Typescript. So `onClick` on `button` is raising a compile-time error saying "Type 'boolean | (() => void)' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement>'.".