# React Native fetching audio from a CDN

Tags: javascript, react-native, audio

I'm currently working on an app and need to fetch a lot of audio from external websites.

This would be an example for one:

"https://cdn.islamic.network/quran/audio/128/ar.alafasy/1.mp3"

I've been looking all over but couldn't really find the best way of going about this, would love if someone more experience could shed some light on this.

Much appreciated

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Hi can you please explain what exactly you need to do with the audio?

In HTML you could do [this](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp):

```html
<audio controls>
  <source src="https://cdn.islamic.network/quran/audio/128/ar.alafasy/1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

to let the user use the audio.

If it has to do with React.js (as you tagged), [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47686478/19497251) should help you out.

To play an Audio File onClick, just take a look at the following example:

```js
import React from 'react';

function App() {
  let audio = new Audio("/christmas.mp3")

  const start = () => {
    audio.play()
  }

  return (
    < div >
      <button onClick={start}>Play</button>
    </div >
  );
}

export default App;
```

This example was provided in a duplicate found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54114171/how-to-play-an-mp3-once-onclick-in-react) by a user named [hunter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4057885/hunter).

Comment: hey, I'm trying to have a modal that onPress plays that specific sound. I thought maybe there is a public library people prefer to use for that, it ideally needs to work over a js file

Comment: doesnt have to be modal, button is fine too. Just trying to figure out how to play an audio over a link, when onPress triggers

Comment: hey, thanks for your help :)

but in this case I'd need to download the audio file right?

could I just paste in the link instead of the .mp3

Comment: you can just paste in the link