# Why does my "Audio-Button" don`t play a sound (onClick)

Tags: reactjs, audio

I am struggeling on finding out why my button dont play a sound when I click on it. The console.log() test works fine, but the -part dont. I also tried some npm-packets to solve the problem, but it seems like my code has a general problem. Whats wrong with it? Can someone help me?

The main.js :

```
import Button from './button';

class Drumpad extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
        this.state = { 
              Q:
              {
                id: 'Q',
                name: 'Q',
                src: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/drums/Heater-1.mp3'
              },
          }
    }
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={test}>
        <div id='row1'>
        <Button cfg={this.state.Q}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And the button.js:

```
class Button extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        }
      }
      handleClick = () => {
        console.log(this.props.cfg.src);
        return (
          <audio ref='audioClick' src={this.props.cfg.src} type='audio/mp3' autoPlay>
          );
        };
  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <button style={buttonStyle} onClick={this.handleClick}>
            <h1>{this.props.cfg.name}</h1>
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Playing sound in reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47686345/playing-sound-in-reactjs)

Comment: Hey Brune, this was not a report but a friendly tag so that you and others can reference to a previously asked question which is similar to yours. That's how stackoverflow works, I hope you read the guidelines?

Answer (score 2):

The `handleClick` method in `button.js` returns an `<audio>` element, which is redundant, since you would like to *play* the sound `onClick`.

Instead I used a `Audio` constructor to create an instance of the audio clip, using the url provided as props, which I set to state.

Then I use a callback to invoke the `play()` method on it.

```
  handleClick = () => {
    const audio = new Audio(this.props.cfg.src);
    this.setState({ audio }, () => {
      this.state.audio.play();
    });
  };
```

So your `button.js` becomes something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

const buttonStyle = {};

export default class Button extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      audio: false
    };
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    console.log(this.props.cfg.src);
    const audio = new Audio(this.props.cfg.src);
    this.setState({ audio }, () => {
      this.state.audio.play();
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button style={buttonStyle} onClick={this.handleClick}>
          <h1>{this.props.cfg.name}</h1>
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Your `main.js` remains as is.

Here is a working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/0y8vkqwvrp).

Comment: Thank you so much. I`m going to check the solution this evening and report if everything is good :))))

Comment: Please do, I have attached the codesandbox tho and it works there.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the solution works. I will now going to understand whats wrong with my solution.

Comment: Consider upvoting / accepting the answer if it works for you. :)

Comment: Upvoted! Thank you very much. You know, I learn for my own and sometimes it`s very hard to find my way :)))