# Importing audio files in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm having trouble importing an audio file in my TypeScript/React app (made with create-react-app).

I'm trying to import the file like this:

```
import note from "./audio/note1s.mp3";
```

But I'm receiving the TypeScript error that says:

> Cannot find module './audio/note1s.mp3' or its corresponding type declarations.

If I add `// @ts-ignore` above that line to ignore the error, the code runs fine and I'm able to use the file as expected.

How can I configure my project to get rid of these errors? I'm fairly new to TypeScript so I'm sure there is something I'm missing. I don't want to have add in those `@ts-ignore` lines every time I'm importing files.

Comment: given that JS has no way to import audio directly in the slightest, you're clearly using a webpack/babel loader for this: which one: and what does its documentation say about what actual object type it turns into?

Comment: You can't import media files like other typescript files with import ;). Try to load it with the "Audio" class https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement/Audio. Or try to load it with Ajax https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started

Answer (score 1):

`import` statement is usually used to import JavaScript/TypeScript files. Create-react-app [extends](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/#when-to-use-the-public-folder) this list with stylesheets, images, and fonts.

Resources like audio or video should be moved to `public/` folder in your `create-react-app` and can be referenced directly from HTML output.

For example:
Place your `note1s.mp3` file to `public/audio/note1s.mp3`.

[Embed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio) the audio in your App.js using `/audio/note1s.mp3` (without `public/`):

```
return (
        <div className="App">
            <figure>
                <figcaption>Play audio file:</figcaption>
                <audio
                    controls
                    src="/audio/note1s.mp3">
                    Your browser does not support the
                    <code>audio</code> element.
                </audio>
            </figure>
        </div>
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

### One solution

...that I've found is using it like this:

```
const note = require('./audio/note1s.mp3');
```

so after that you can use it with libraries like `use-sound` like:

```
const [play, { stop }] = useSound(note);
```

### Another solution more in the typescript way:

Just add the types to the sound files extensions as [here](https://github.com/joshwcomeau/use-sound/issues/66#issuecomment-815705162) adding a new file in the project named like: `audio.d.ts` with the following:

```
declare module "*.mp3";
declare module "*.wav";
```

and after that you can just:

```
import note from './audio/note1s.mp3';
```